# Missing assembly Microsoft.Phone.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, metadata, .net-assembly

When I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 project, I get this error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/VOgDatf.png]

I have searched on the internet but can't find the solution. They say the `Microsoft.Phone.dll` should be located in `C:\Windows\System32` but it isn't there!

I have also tried to make new blank Windows Phone Project 8.1 and tried to build that immediately and I get the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see the file here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.dll" and here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Designer\Microsoft.Phone.dll"

Comment: Yeah I have it there also... But any idea how to fix error? I got this even when building a blank project ...

Comment: When I add manually reference to it I got this error: Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll.

Comment: which one do you reference? The one from Designer or the other one?

Comment: I tried them all. I get the error because i can't add third party references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722608/cannot-find-type-system-systemexception-in-module-mscorlib-dll-when-i-referenc

Comment: There 2 different type windows phone 8.1 projects silverlight and winrt.  Are you trying to a silverlight windows phone assembly with a phone winrt project?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add Silverlight assembly to Windows Phone 8.1 App Project. You should to distinguish between 8.1 Silverlight and 8.1 WinRT Windows Phone projects.

**EDIT**

If you want to use `Microsoft.Phone.dll` in your 8.1 project, you must to create Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App

1. Create an application
   [image]
2. Choose OS Version
   [image]
3. After that you can user `Microsoft.Phone.dll`
   [image]

But I recommend to create an usual Windows Phone 8.1 Application and use new SDK.

Comment: Create Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project or use new API from WinRT SDK

Comment: I can only select Windows Phone 8.1 App to add ? no silverlight?